# JPA: OneToMany relationship keeps the Collection empty

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

It seems I am having a difficult time understanding JPA and how the OneToMany relationship actually works.

For example, imagine I have an object `Class`

```
@Entity
public class Class {
    @Id
    private String className;

    @OneToMany(cascade = Cascade.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Student> students;

    // Constructors, Getters, Setter
}
```

I also have an object `Student` where it holds Class.

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    private String studentName;

    @ManyToOne
    private Class class;

    // Constructors, Getters, Setter
}
```

Obviously, a student can have multiple classes but forget about that.

Why is that when I build a class and then build a couple students using that class, `findAll()` on the `ClassRepository` returns me an empty set of students.

```
Class class = new Class("CS", new HashSet<>());
classRepository.save(class); // repository has no special functions

Student student1 = new Student("1", class);
Student student2 = new Student("2", class);

studentRepository.save(student1);
studentRepository.save(student2);

classRepository.findAll() // Returns me a List<Class> with only one class object that has an empty set.
```

I was thinking the above code should automatically see that the two students are from that one class and so when I call `buildingRepository.findAll()`, it will return a `Class` object with the students set populated properly.

Is my understanding wrong then? Or is my code wrong? And how can I change it up to fix it?

Comment: Several reasons: 1. your mapping is incorrect; 2. you're setting the student class, but you're not adding the students to the class. Here's how a bidirectional OneToMany must be mapped: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: By default, `@...Many` are loaded lazily, which is a best thing for performance issue. And as you use `Cascade.ALL` you could let the `Class`persist your Student. For me it's normal that `classRepository.findAll()` returns only 1 class since you persisted only 1. For performance issue, I'll suggest you to load students in a separate request not with the `classRepository.findAll()`. Smthg like `classRepository.findClassWithAllStudentsById()` and use `EntityGraph` to load the students.

Comment: You are supposed to map the from object `class` to `student`. Not separately! For example, you could use Json mapping format.

Comment: @JBNizet shouldn't me saving the two students using the class object, add the students to the class? I want it to save those students to the class when doing that. 

Like, the example code I supplied at the end is how I want my logic to work. So when I do `classRepo.findAll()` it should return one `class` with the set having two `student` objects.

Comment: If your mapping was correct, what you did would be sufficient to save the association to the database. If you cleared the persistence context or if you started a new one, then retrieving the class would retrieve its students. But inside that persistence context, since what you saved is a class without any students, what you'll retrieve is that precise  class, without any student: it's your responsibility to maintain the coherence of the graph inside a persistence context (i.e. a transaction)

Comment: I realized that Sping JPA doesn't work good with Set. In some cases in my code I was facing empty sets in theorically right mappings and couldn't realize the reason until I decided to replace them with Lists. Maybe this is a bug... I don't know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose:

**1. Unidirectional `@OneToMany`:**

```
@Entity
public class Class {
    @Id
    private String className;

    @OneToMany(cascade = Cascade.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Student> students=new ArrayList<>();

    // Constructors, Getters, Setter
}

@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    private String studentName;

    // Constructors, Getters, Setter
}
```

Now, if we persist one `Class`:

```
Class class1=new Class("name1");
class1.getStudents().add(new Student("student1Name"));
// then you can make a save of class1 in db
classRepository.save(class);
```

**2. Unidirectional `@OneToMany` with `@JoinColumn`:**

To fix the aforementioned extra join table issue, we just need to add the `@JoinColumn` in the mix:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "class_id")
private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
```

**3. Bidirectional `@OneToMany`:**

The best way to map a @OneToMany association is to rely on the @ManyToOne side to propagate all entity state changes:

```
@Entity
public class Class {
    @Id
    private String className;

    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "class",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<Student> students=new ArrayList<>();

    // Constructors, Getters, Setter
    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        students.add(student);
        student.setClass(this);
    }

    public void removeStudent(Student student) {
        students.remove(student);
        student.setClass(null);
    }
}


@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    private String studentName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "class_id")
    private Class class;

}
```

And to persist:

```
Class c1=new Class("className1");
c1.addStudent(new Student("StudentNAme1"));
c1.addStudent(new Student("StudentNAme2"));
c1.addStudent(new Student("StudentNAme3"));
classRepository.save(c1);
```

Answer (score 1):

After trying for multiple hours, I figured out the reason is that in some cases set just not work, and list is needed to get the child entity.

So instead of using

```
@OneToMany(cascade = Cascade.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Student> students;
```

You can try

```
@OneToMany(cascade = Cascade.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Student> students;
```